# Property 'identifier' not valid in version 51.0

Tags: deployment, api-version, deployment-error

Trying to deploy from environment to another a LightningPage, I get this error:

*Property 'identifier' not valid in version 51.0*

I don't know where I can specify the version of the page (or change it) in the XML archive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>collapsed</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>enableActionsConfiguration</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>enableActionsInNative</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>hideChatterActions</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>numVisibleActions</name>
                    <value>3</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>force:highlightsPanel</componentName>
                <identifier>force_highlightsPanel</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>hideUpdateButton</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>variant</name>
                    <value>linear</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>runtime_sales_pathassistant:pathAssistant</componentName>
                <identifier>runtime_sales_pathassistant_pathAssistant</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>header</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentName>force:detailPanel</componentName>
                <identifier>force_detailPanel</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>detailTabContent</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>test</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>lock</name>
                    <value>false</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>recordId</name>
                    <value>{recordId}</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>testLWC</componentName>
                <identifier>testLWC</identifier>
                <visibilityRule>
                    <criteria>
                        <leftValue>{!Record.Estado__c}</leftValue>
                        <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                        <rightValue>New</rightValue>
                    </criteria>
                </visibilityRule>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>Facet-24adadsa-0adsa4-43df-9zxd2-8wdwads25279</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>active</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>body</name>
                    <value>detailTabContent</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>title</name>
                    <value>Standard.Tab.detail</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
                <identifier>detailTab</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>body</name>
                    <value>Facet-212da58-0c54-4wqedf-9dasd2-892dzxad105279</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>title</name>
                    <value>ManagerTest</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
                <identifier>customTab</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>maintabs</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>tabs</name>
                    <value>maintabs</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
                <identifier>flexipage_tabset</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>parentFieldApiName</name>
                    <value>ManagerTest__c.Id</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>relatedListApiName</name>
                    <value>ManagerTest2__r</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>relatedListComponentOverride</name>
                    <value>NONE</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>rowsToDisplay</name>
                    <value>10</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>showActionBar</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>force:relatedListSingleContainer</componentName>
                <identifier>force_relatedListSingleContainer</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <mode>Replace</mode>
        <name>sidebar</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>My RecordPage</masterLabel>
    <parentFlexiPage>flexipage__default_rec_L</parentFlexiPage>
    <sobjectType>MyRecordPage__c</sobjectType>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:recordHomeTemplateDesktop</name>
    </template>
    <type>RecordPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Where can I put the  for changing the version to 53.0 ?

Comment: The version needs to be updated in the package xml which gets created while deployment.

Comment: thanks you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to update the Metadata API version you should navigate to your `package.xml` manifest file and update the `<version>` tag to the desired one, so it would be something similar to:

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<version>53.0</version> </Package>
```

Additionally, can find information regarding this file [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm).

As mentioned by Phil, if you're using `sfdx` then you should update the API version on the `sfdx-project.json` file by editing the `<sourceApiVersion>` tag instead. An example would be:

```
{ 
"packageDirectories" : [ 
    { 
      "path": "force-app", 
      "default": true
    }
],
"namespace": "", 
"sfdcLoginUrl" : "https://login.salesforce.com", 
"sourceApiVersion": "53.0"
}
```

And information regarding this file can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm).

Comment: If using SFDX consider the API version in the sfdx-project.json instead. Applies to all metadata that does not included a dedicated version identifier.

Comment: @PhilW you're right! Updated the original answer to include this approach as well.

Comment: Solved, thank you!