# Flow section headers

Tags: visual-workflow, deployment, deployment-error

I have a flow which has sections. Each section has a header which works completely fine.
When we promote this flow to another sandbox section headers are getting removed from flow.
Please provide solutions on how to overcome this.

Comment: what version are you using the metadata api used to promote to the next sandbox? Flow sections were introduced in Summer 22 (V55.0). If your deployment tool is using V54 or lower, it won't pick up this metadata construct

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and as cropredy said it is an API version issue.

From your description it seems you may be using change sets to move between orgs in which case updating the API version that the flow is using should be enough but if you're also using source (as in my case) - I needed to retrieve the source which was missing the [regionContainerType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) tag.

```
        <fields>
            <name>Header1</name>
            <fieldText>Header Text</fieldText>
            <fieldType>RegionContainer</fieldType>
            <fields>
                ...
            </fields>
            <isRequired>false</isRequired>
            <regionContainerType>SectionWithHeader</regionContainerType>
        </fields>
```

As an additional note: ensure you check that API version of the tools you are using - I had set the API version of the flow in setup to be v55.0 (which updated correctly when retrieving the source) however my VSCode and sfdx were set to v51.0 so the metadata was still missing the correct tag. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371034/property-identifier-not-valid-in-version-51-0) covers updating the API version in either the `package.xml` or `sfdx-project.json` files, in my case I updated `sourceApiVersion` in `sfdx-project.json` to `55.0` and then retrieved the correct source using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -p path/to/file`.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
}
```

This source could then be deployed correctly to a new environment with section headers intact.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential causes of section headers getting removed from flows when promoting to another sandbox in Salesforce. Here are a few possible solutions to consider:

1.Make sure that the flow version being promoted is the same as the one with the working section headers. It's possible that an earlier version of the flow is being promoted, which could be missing the section headers.

2.Check that the sections themselves are being promoted with the flow. It's possible that the sections were created in a separate component (e.g. a custom Lightning component) and are not being included when the flow is promoted.

3.Review the permissions of the users in the sandbox where the headers are getting removed. It's possible that some users don't have the necessary permissions to view or interact with the sections in the flow.

4.If none of the above solutions work, consider reaching out to Salesforce support